# Convert set of .json files into .transcript files

Tags: python, json, botframework, chatbot

I have list of .json files. Actually these .json files has been created by chat bot service.

For every conversation with chatbot, in backend our service bot application is creating .json files. Now, these .json files need to be analysed for finding conversation flow.

Bot emulator is what we are looking for, where the transcript file would be given as input and on the emulator we can directly check out the whole flow of conversation.

Already we have a lot of conversation files in .json format. Now I need a way to convert all these .json files into . transcript file, so that it could be used on Bot framework emulator.

I am using python 3.

Comment: Can you post any code you have written, along with any examples of json or transcript files, in the question? Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), right now we are missing too much context to effectively help you

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then provide more details about your problem and what you have tried. As it stands there is not a lot we can help you with.

Comment: Script what i wrote was about to read json file tags one after another. But now requirement is to convert  .json files of one conversation  into .transcript file, so that same could get used over bot framework emulator.

Comment: What i can tell is within a folder there will be some 10 to 15 json files and these different json files will be connected to each other with one ID. These set of .json files should be converted into one .transcript file. And then created .transcript file would be used over a bot framework emulator to look for all conversation . The link creation from the conversation ID will be done by bot framework simulator. Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-debug-transcript?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: I have no idea, when query gets posted, it will be down voted. As if, Every one here is a genius. I agree my way of asking query might be  wrong , if i will spend more time posting stuffs over here, i will come to know how to do it.

Comment: Please, anybody could help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Okie. So this was the dumbest for me to update such a silly question over stack overflow. After looking hard enough,  what i did was merging all json files data into one file and then renaming that file with an extension of .transcript .